# How to sort this list, where the lowest start time shows first

Tags: python

i am doing a class assignment, when i run the tester the teacher gave us outputs the dictionary named Calendar with another dictionary inside of it called Date. Inside the Date there is start time, end time and a title, in the output the highest start time shows first instead of the lowest start time.

i tried sorting the list but when i do that, it only outputs the lowest start date leaving the second date out.

```
not_date = {
        "start": start_time,
        "end": end_time,
        "title": title
    }
if start_time in range(1, 25):
    if end_time in range(1, 25):
        if start_time <= end_time:
            if date in calendar:
                calendar[date].append(not_date)
                return True
            else:
                calendar[date] = []
                calendar[date].append(not_date)
                return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
else:
    return False
```

we expected this return value:

```
{'2019-07-18': [{'start': 14, 'end': 15, 'title': 'MAT157 Tutorial'}, {'start': 16, 'end': 18, 'title': 'Gym'}]}
```

but your code returned this:

```
{'2019-07-18': [{'start': 16, 'end': 18, 'title': 'Gym'}, {'start': 14, 'end': 15, 'title': 'MAT157 Tutorial'}]}
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you add a MCVE?

Comment: To sort the data you need to use a `for` loop to move/iterate through data and check each data using `if` statement. If order is wrong you need to exchange two datas

Comment: @SuvenPandey In general, it is not recommended to use such an imperative approach to sorting, if a higher-level approach is possible (and it seems to be, in this case)

Comment: @gmds It seems like the assignment is from beginner python classes. From my experience when an instructor says `sort` in beginner classes he means using two for loops and a if statement to check values and exchange their position if necessary. I dont expect the instructor meant something like `sorted (my_dict.keys())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dict:

```
d= {'2019-07-18': [{'start': 14, 'end': 15, 'title': 'MAT157 Tutorial'}, {'start': 16, 'end': 18, 'title': 'Gym'}]}
```

Code:

```
sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: is it possible to explain what happens after the key = lambda ?